# MongoDB slow to read a collection in Studio 3T

Tags: mongodb

We have a MongoDB replica set using mongo version 3.6.12 and use Studio 3T to connect with read preference as "nearest" node.

One collection has size 78 GB and 15 million documents only take 1 second to load in studio 3T, but the other collection has size 44GB and 130 thousand documents take more than 40 second to load in studio 3T.

Similar slowness experience from pymongo.

Any suggestion for the slow performance of that smaller collection?

Answer (score 1):

The documents are on average 5.2kB in the first collection and 338kB in the second collection. So as the documents are on avergage 65 times bigger in the second, it's not surprising that they take much longer to load.